# System('hostname') from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, matlab, code-translation

What is the best way to translate the following MATLAB command to Python?

```
[~,hostname] = system('hostname');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an example on Kong's explanation, you can always wrap the syscall inside a `try` block like this:

```
import sys
import errno
try:
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
except socket.error as s_err:
    print >> sys.stderr, ("error: gethostname: error %d (%s): %s" %
                          (s_err.errno, errno.errorcode[s_err.errno],
                           s_err.strerror))
```

This will format the error information as something like `error: gethostname: error 13 (EACCES): Permission denied`, although this is just a hypothetical situation.

---

If you want to use an external process in the way `system()` does (but without spawning a shell), you can execute a command using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["hostname"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
cmdout, cmderr = cmd.communicate()
print "Command exited with code %d" % cmd.returncode
print "Command output: %s" % cmdout
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`gethostname()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) from the`socket` interface, which is "*available on all modern Unix systems, Windows, MacOS, and probably additional platforms.*" (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html#module-socket)):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostname()
'DK07'
```

If `gethostname()` fails for some reason, it would raise an exception. That is different however from if the name is omitted or empty, in which case it is interpreted as the local host.

Another portable equivalent (*just for the sake of completeness*) is

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.node()
'DK07'
```

You should also take a look at [Cong Ma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29618453/4686625) for a good example.

Comment: what about the status?

Comment: @overcomer Oh, I was under the impression that matlab line simply produced the computer name. Can you add to your question what exactly you are attempting to get for information? What else does that command give you?

Comment: it gives me the status. A status indicates that the command completed successfully.

Comment: If the command does not complete successfully an exception is raised. I think you should't need to catch it.

Comment: ^This. I'll edit it into my question, thanks @EmanuelePaolini